# How to solve authentication error in Google Ads API

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I have integrated google ads api in our companies CRM. It is only one api call using "KeywordPlanIdeaService". It works well in test-mode.

Next step is to "publish". But if i run the script to get the refresh_token and follow the URL, i get the "Authentification error" with deleloper hint
"redirect_uri: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"

What could be wrong?

Comment: can you share the actual code for the creation of the used credentials object? Obfuscate actual keys of course... You are using a serviceaccount, correct?

Comment: just as a note, the issue is with the redirect URI. If you made any changes to the OAuth section on Google's end, you need to delete the current stored credentials you have, and do the auth from start... **SIDENOTE**: [This](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python_1) is excellent documentation for OAuth2.0 with Google APIs

Comment: i followed this docu: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call
i have recreated credentials after first fail with no effect. There should be no redirects, because you get access_token once you allow the api

Comment: Following the rabbithole from the link provided, I find [this line](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/authentication/generate_refresh_token.py#L35) so the next question becomes: where exactly are you running this code? Webserver? App? Mobile?

Comment: Seems like it was a major update since february. i have a whole different generate_refresh_token.py without any redirect_url.Unfortunatly, I won't be able to test it until Monday. Thx for hint!

Comment: As a note on that, for production environments you should fix the versions of the libraries you use to prevent issues like the one you have. If you're running in an environment such as fe. Google App Engine, they might pull newer libraries once an instance is started, and if the newer version doesn't have proper backwards compatability, it might break your app. But good to hear that you've (likely) identified the issue.